# Android - How to change Navigation Bar location programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

i've an activity displayed in landscape mode.
I want the navigation bar to be located on the side (the software one who is displayed on device without phisical buttons).

Just like Waze:
[image: waze screen]

I've searched but i can't find a way to create a layout as the one above.
Can you give me any suggestions on how to achive this result?

Comment: you don't have to: just put your activity in landscape mode and android automatically displays the navbar on the right side

Comment: of course, this is dependend on the device you are running it on, but you can't really influence it since the device decides where to show the navbar. Most smartphones put on the right in landscape, whereas tablets and some phablets leave it at the bottom

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to replicate that layout on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your activity in landscape mode, e.g., by specifying `orientation="landscape"` or `orientation="sensorLandscape"` in your app's manifest file for the activity.

The device then decides where to show the navigation bar: smartphones show it on the right side to give your app some more screen space, most tablets leave it at the bottom since their displays are larger.

Comment: My activity is already in landscape but the navigation bar is displyed on the bottom (on tablet).

Comment: tablets always show the navbar at the bottom, try it on a smaller device (up to 6", maybe 7") that should show the navbar on the side.